# How to create input name field with string-variable schema in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use VueJs, i need to extract javascript variable to generate hidden fields.

But i need to set the name by the index of the variable.

I want to use zig-zag naming schema.

like,

```
 <input type="text" name="segment[{index}][field_name]" :value="{value}">
```

**Javascript Variable:**

```
    var test_template = {
                        0: {
                            nb: 2
                        },
                        1: {
                            nb: 1
                        },
                        2: {
                            nb: 4
                        }
                    };
```

**Foreach with Variable to Generate Hidden Fields :**

```
    <div v-for="(a,index) in test_template" class="row">            
      <input type="hidden" :name="segment[index][nb]" :value="a.nb">
   </div>
```

Here, **:name** is a dynamic instance for access vuejs values.
**index** is vuejs variable but "**segment**" is not a vuejs variable, its actually a string.

But i need this schema to generate array of inputs.

Is this possible ?

Or Any other solutions are there ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Have you tried segment + a.nb ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To create input elements with dynamic names by index, you can use the `+` in a JS expression to concatenate:

```
<div v-for="(a,index) in test_template" class="row">            
  <input type="hidden" :name="'segment[' + index + '][nb]'" :value="a.nb">
</div>
```

Generates:

```
<input type="hidden" name="section[0][nb]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="section[1][nb]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="section[2][nb]" value="4">
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

Comment: You can also use JS6 interpolation. `:name="\`segment[${index}][nb]\`"`

Answer (score 15):

I ran across the same problem as you, and here is how i fixed it !

make a method like this in your vue-instance

```
getInputName(index, dataName){
      return "items["+index+"]["+dataName+"]";
    }
```

then you can use it like this:

```
<input v-bind:name="getInputName(index, 'name')" type="text" v-model="item.name">
<input v-bind:name="getInputName(index, 'price')" type="text" v-model="item.price">
```

which will give you this post result:

```
"items" =>[
    0 =>[
      "name" => "test"
      "price" => "23"
    ],
    1 =>[
      "name" => "jakke"
      "price" => "99,2312"
    ]
]
```

And thats it...

Cheers,
Sipman