# Handle Multi Data Like Array in Form

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How Can I Send Form Data like Array

look at the below code , I Can’t set Index in product_attribute[‘index must be here’][‘key’]

```
<tr v-for="index in attributes">
    <td class="text-left">
    <input type="text" name="product_attribute['index must be here']['key']" value="" placeholder="attribute" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
</td>
    <td class="text-left">
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea name="product_attribute['index must be here']['value']" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: finally I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054018/how-to-create-input-name-field-with-string-variable-schema-in-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

You could bind it using `v-bind:name` or shortly `:name` as follows :

```
<input type="text" :name="product_attribute[index]['key']"  ...
```

and

```
  <textarea :name="product_attribute[index]['value']"
```

Comment: I tried with this but in console ReferenceError: product_attribute is not defined

Comment: in fact , I don't want to use ajax for send data I want send with form request

Comment: so you should do `:name="'product_attribute['+index+']['value']" `