# laravel store combined data as object in a single field

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to store repeater data in database Using laravel. But for that I need to combine some data with different values.

my form looks like this--

```
 <div v-for="(tab, tabIndex) in tabs" :key="tab.id">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 d-flex">
                <label>HouseAreaTypes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4 d-flex">
                <select
                    v-model="tab.selectedHouseType"
                    @change="getDecor(tabIndex)"
                    name="houseAreaTypeId">
                    <option v-for="houseType in houseTypes" :key="houseType.id" :value="houseType.id">{{ houseType.name }}</option>
                </select>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button @click="addTab">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button v-if="tabIndex > 0" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-2 ml-2" @click="removeTab(tabIndex, tab)">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div v-for="(row, rowIndex) in tab.rows" :key="row.id">
                <table class="table table-borderless col-md-12">
                    <thead>
                    <th>DecorationType</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">Rate</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2">TotalAmount</th>
                    <th class="col-md-2"></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <td>
                        <select
                            v-model="row.selectedDecor"
                            @change="getDescription(tabIndex,rowIndex) "name="decId">
                            <option v-for="decorType in tab.decorTypes" :key="decorType.id" :value="decorType.id">
                                {{ decorType.name }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" name="des" v-model="row.selectedDes"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="number" name="rate" v-model="row.selectedRate" @change="calculateLineTotal(tabIndex,rowIndex)"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-1">
                        <input type="number" min="0" name="qty" v-model="row.selectedQty" @change="calculateLineTotal(tabIndex,rowIndex)"
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-3">
                        <input
                            type="number" name="totalAmount" v-model="row.line_total"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button  v-if="rowIndex == Object.keys(tab.rows).length -1" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2 ml-2" @click="addRow(tabIndex)">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button  type="button"
                                @click="removeRow(rowIndex, row,tabIndex)">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
```

my migration looks like this--

```
 Schema::create('house_area_carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('houseAreaTypeId')->nullable();
            $table->text('houseAreaCartInfo')->nullable()->comment('Object (decorationTypeId, descriptionOfDecoration, qty, rate, totalAmount)');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I already have done the frontend part using vue. Here I need to store multiple **houseAreaTypeId** but in the **houseAreaCartInfo** I need to commbine  **decorationTypeId, descriptionOfDecoration, qty, rate, totalAmount** these datas. I am attaching an image so you understand well

[Iamge to understand the topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3GQC.png)

**updates**

in my controller --

```
public function createCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $cart = HouseAreaCart::create([
            'houseAreaTypeId' => $request->houseAreaTypeId,
            'houseAreaCartInfo' => $request->get('houseAreaCartInfo'),
            'houseAreaCartInfo' =>[
                'rate' => $request->rate,
                'qty' => $request->qty,
                'decId' => $request->decId,
                'des' => $request->des,
                'totalAmount' => $request->totalAmount
            ]
        ]);
        dd($cart);
        return response()->json($cart);
    }
```

I am getting this after dd.

```
 "houseAreaTypeId" => "2"
    "houseAreaCartInfo" => "{"rate":["11","2"],"qty":["8","1"],"decId":["2","3"],"des":["Nostrum dolorem qui","Veniam architecto l"],"totalAmount":["88.00","2.00"]}"
```

But when I add another **houseAreaTypeId** it's showing only the last **houseAreaTypeId** I added.

Now how do I process multiple **houseAreaTypeId** in my controller and save it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The easieast way will be attribute casting to `json` or `array`:

```php
// add to the model:
protected $casts = [
  'houseAreaCartInfo' => 'array',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

In the controller you would simply assign to the model an array from your request (or use `update` method on the model - will work the same):

```php
$cartModel->houseAreaCartInfo = $request->get('houseAreaCartInfo');
```

then whenever you get that value it will come as an array (same as in the request):

```php
$cartModel->houseAreaCartInfo

[
  'des' => ...,
  'qty' => ...,
  ...
]
```

In your request I suggest validation to make sure this value comes as an array and is stored properly
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: do you get errors, is the value not populated, what's not working?

Comment: I tried this. but It's not working.

``public function createCart(Request $request, $id)`
    {
       
        $cart = HouseAreaCart::create([
            'houseAreaTypeId' => $request->houseAreaTypeId,
            'houseAreaCartInfo' => $request->get('houseAreaCartInfo'),
            'houseAreaCartInfo' =>
        [
          'rate' => $request->rate,
          'qty' => $request->qty
        ]
        ]);
        return response()->json($cart);
    }`

Comment: Array to string conversion-- this is showing

Comment: did you use the attribute mutator/cast as in the link provided?

Comment: '<pre>class HouseAreaCart extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded=[];
}
</pre>'
I used this

Comment: you need to add `casts` property - see the update in my answer.

Comment: Yeah. It's working now. But how do I insert Multiple values? Did you see the attached picture?

Comment: It's more of a vue question at this point. You would want something like `:name='"houseAreaCartInfo[' + rowIndex + '][des]"'`. You may check more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072868/19766732

Eloquent will store the nested JSON the same, so that part should work fine for you

Comment: there are multiple houseAreaCartInfo under a single houseAreaTypeId. but its just storing one houseAreaCartInfo

Comment: I updated my code. Please check when you have time

Answer (score 0):

Your migration should like,

```
$table->text('houseAreaCartInfo')->nullable()
```

anf then, Make sure your request is something like the following,

```
$request = [
    'houseAreaTypeId' => 'required|int', //or array as your choice
    'houseAreaCartInfo' => 'required|array',
    'houseAreaCartInfo.*.decerationType' => 'required|array', //or int as your choice
    'houseAreaCartInfo.*.description' => 'required|string',
    'houseAreaCartInfo.*.rate' => 'required|int',
    'houseAreaCartInfo.*.quantity' => 'required|int',
];
```

Then in your model, cast the column as array,

```
protected $cast = [
    'houseAreaCartInfo' => 'array'
];
```

Finally, you can create model by using eloquent, There should be no error.

Comment: I dont Understand. Can you please explain briefly about the insert method?

Comment: Sure, give me couple of hours, I'm bit busy now. I will explain

Comment: yeah. sure. thank you for taking my problem seriously

Comment: I updated my code. Please check when you have time

Comment: It seems there is something goes wrong with your `form`. Check the frontend form. 

It must have the following structure.

`form: {
  houseAreaType: {},
  cartInfo: [],
}`

then cart info must me array of objects.

Comment: Can you show me the dump of the request please.

Comment: I have already updated the code with dump. Now I have added the form structure. Please check.
`return {
                tabs: [{
                    selectedHouseType: "",
                    decorTypes: {},
                    rows: [{
                        selectedDecor: "",
                        selectedDes: "",
                        selectedQty: "",
                        selectedRate: "",
                        line_total: 0,
                        descriptions: {},
                    }],
                }],  
                houseTypes: {}, 
            }`